# Not Solvable in Z3. Why?

Tags: z3

Not Solvable in Z3. Why?

My Program:

```
;x = 2x + 2 (This on Underlaying DB is always increasing as X > Y in DB)
(declare-const x0 Real)
(declare-const xn Real)
(declare-const n Real)
(push)
(assert (= x0 42))
(assert (= xn (+ (* x0 (^ 2 n)) (* 2 (- (^ 2 n) 1)) ) )) ; recurrence relation
(assert (> xn 700))
(check-sat-using qfnra-nlsat)
(get-model); to find a satisfiable valuation
(pop); removes any assertion


-----------------------------
Z3 Answer:
-----------------------------


 unknown 
    (model 
    (define-fun n () Real 0.0) 
    (define-fun xn () Real 42.0) 
    (define-fun x0 () Real 42.0) 
    )
```

---

I tried with integer also: 
According to the values in database  'n' should come as 4, but it is coming as 0.

Please see into it and anyone please help me.

Comment: `unknown` could be due to the use of non-linear arithmetic (undecidable). Also, if there are multiple solutions to a problem, you'll just get one of them. Is your "database solution" the only possible one?

Comment: Yes, Database Solution is the only one solution!

Answer (score 0):

`unknown` means the model is "alleged," i.e., may or may not be correct. Since your problem contains non-linear terms (exponentiation), this is to be expected.

Indeed, the model suggests `xn = 42`, which contradicts the assumption `xn > 700` in your program. The model given is bogus. But you *cannot* blame z3 for that, since it already told you `unknown`. It's beyond Z3's capabilities to solve your query.

Comment: Thank you @levent